# insert to sql server

Tags: c#, insert, sql-server-2008-r2, ms-access-2000

I have to insert data from ms access to sql server. My logic is:

1. Get list of names in ms access.
2. Disable foreign key and triggers before insertion.
3. Read each table.
4. Change RowState of each row by SetAdded() method.
5. Finally insert it using command builder

**Error**

One field in table(Ms Access ) has datatype Date/Time. But it got only time value NO DATE part. During insertion it gives error. "   SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.  "

In dataset visualizer i saw value(s)  12/30/1899 1:01:01 AM.

How to solve it.

```
        try
        {
            oleCon = new OleDbConnection();
            oleCon.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\Client Work\Client Docs\Don\ABCMotor.mdb;User Id=admin;Password=;";
            oleCon.Open();
            dt = new DataTable();
            dt = oleCon.GetSchema("tables");

            sqlCon = new SqlConnection(@"Server=ACER-PC\SQLEXPRESS2008R2;Database=ABC;Integrated Security=SSPI;");
            sqlCon.Open();
            SqlCommandBuilder sqlCmdB = new SqlCommandBuilder();
            sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
            SqlTransaction sqlTran;
            sqlTran = sqlCon.BeginTransaction();
            sqlCmd.Connection = sqlCon;
            sqlCmd.Transaction = sqlTran;
            sqlCmd.CommandText = "sp_msforeachtable";
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Command1", "ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all");
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
            sqlCmd.Connection = sqlCon;
            sqlCmd.Transaction = sqlTran;
            sqlCmd.CommandText = "sp_msforeachtable";
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Clear();
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Command1", "ALTER TABLE ? DISABLE TRIGGER  all");
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                if (row["Table_Name"].ToString().StartsWith("MSys") == false)
                {
                    oleDa = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [" + row["Table_Name"] + "]", oleCon);
                    ds = new DataSet();
                    oleDa.Fill(ds);

                    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from [" + row["Table_Name"] + "]", sqlCon);
                        sqlDa.SelectCommand.Transaction = sqlTran;
                        foreach (DataRow item in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                        {
                            item.SetAdded();
                        }
                        sqlCmdB.DataAdapter = sqlDa;

                        sqlCmdB.GetInsertCommand();

                        sqlDa.Update(ds);                                         
                    }
                }
            }

            sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
            sqlCmd.Connection = sqlCon;
            sqlCmd.Transaction = sqlTran;
            sqlCmd.CommandText = "sp_msforeachtable";
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Clear();
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Command1", "ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT all");
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
            sqlCmd.Connection = sqlCon;
            sqlCmd.Transaction = sqlTran;

            sqlCmd.CommandText = "sp_msforeachtable";
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Clear();
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Command1", "ALTER TABLE ? ENABLE TRIGGER  all");
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlTran.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: *In dataset visualizer i saw value(s) 12/30/1899 1:01:01 AM.* Look more closely. I load data from JET databases on occasions and if I get this error, usually a user has fat fingered a year. E.g. 201 instead of 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `FillSchema()` to ensure your data adapter knows exactly what datatypes it is dealing with.

```
OleDbDataAdapter.FillSchema("", SchemaType.Source)
```

You will still need to call the `Fill()` method to get the data.

Comment: Here is the changed code   ds.Tables.Add();//added 1 table so it will not give any error 
                        oleDa.FillSchema(ds.Tables[0], schemaType.Source);//VS gives error on placing "" instead of ds.Tables[0].  It does not give error but it does NOT Insert either.